# Django queryset annotate field to be a list/queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I'm trying to use django annotation to create queryset field which is a list of values of some related model attribute.

```
queryset = ...
qs = queryset.annotate(
    list_field=SomeAggregateFunction(
        Case(When(related_model__field="abc"), then="related_model__id")
    ),
    list_elements=Count(F('list_field'))
)
```

I was thinking about about concatenating all these id with some separator, but i don't know the appropriate functions. Another solution is to make list_field a `queryset`. I know this syntax is wrong. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using psql

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using `postgresql` and `django >= 1.9`, you could use postgres specific aggregating functions e.g.
 [`ArrayAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

> Returns a list of values, including nulls, concatenated into an array.

In case, you need to concatenate these values using a delimiter, you could also use [`StringAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg).

Comment: Were you able to work out the conditional expression inside the aggregation? I would like to know how.

Comment: See my comment below

Comment: I see what I was missing. I was using `then=F("related_model__pk")` and that's why it was not working. Thank you.

Comment: How can i make it a set of the values though?

Answer (score 10):

I have done something like that:

```
qs = queryset \
    .annotate(
        field_a=ArrayAgg(Case(When(
            related_model__field="A",
            then="related_model__pk")
        )),
        field_b=ArrayAgg(Case(When(
            related_model__field="B",
            then="related_model__pk")
        )),
        field_c=ArrayAgg(Case(When(
            related_model__field="C",
            then="related_model__pk")
        ))
    )
```

Now there are lists of `None` or `pk` under each `field_a`, `field_b` and `field_c` for every object in queryset. You can also define other default value for `Case` instead of `None`.

Comment: Is it possible to filter out the None items from the array field?

Comment: I've filtered them out in app using python `filter` function. I'm not sure if it is possible on the database level.

Comment: `field_a=ArrayAgg("related_model__pk", filter=Q(related_model__field="A"))` is a bit cleaner. However, I am not sure if `filter` was supported by `ArrayAgg` when this answer was posted.

Comment: Just discovered ArrayAgg thanks to this post and can't believe how awesome it is.  I needed to annotate the counts of related objects, but also get a list of their ids.  ArrayAgg to the rescue.